# Ocultar ou mostrar campo de acordo com a opção selecionada

Tags: css, html5, ajax

Estou precisando de uma grande ajuda.. Tenho um formulário php pronto, porém o usuário solicitou que após selecionar o Solicitante, o campo de nome do solicitante deve aparecer de acordo com o Solicitante selecionado.
São 3 opções de solicitante (Agência, Corporativo, Executivo).
Se for Agência ou Corporativo, habilita o mesmo campo de nome, se for Executivo habilita outro campo. Se for sem identificação, não habilita nenhuma opção de nome.

Bom, pesquisei diversos códigos aqui no fórum mas nenhum consegui encaixar no meu código.
O meu formulário está dividido em 3 arquivos php.
Tenho o Index, o AJAX onde carrega os campos com Bootstrap e o arquivo SQL onde estão os Selects na base.

Estou tentando incluir o código para ocultar o campo, dentro do Ajax.php
Vou inserir abaixo, como está o códigono arquivo, para que possam analisar e ver onde estou errando.

```
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
    include 'classificador_Eventos_sql2.php';
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}

    $seccion = $_POST["seccion"];
    @$cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
    @$subcliente = $_POST['subcliente'];
    @$executivo = $_POST['executivo'];
    @$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
    @$subtipo = $_POST['subtipo'];
    @$iata = $_POST['iata'];
    @$nomeiata = $_POST['nomeiata'];

    if($seccion == "carregarForm"){ carregarForm();}
    if($seccion == "carregarSubcliente"){ carregarSubcliente($cliente);}
    if($seccion == "carregarSubtipo"){ carregarSubtipo($tipo);}
    if($seccion == "carregarIATA"){ carregarIATA($iata);}
    if($seccion == "guardar"){ guardar($cliente, $subcliente, $tipo, $subtipo, $iata, $nomeiata, $executivo);}


function carregarForm(){

    $tipos = obtiene_filtros('tipo', null);
    $clientes = obtiene_Cliente('cliente', null);
    $filtro_Executivo = obtiene_Executivo();


    $out = '<div class="panel panel-default col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" style="padding:0px;">
                <div class="panel-body" id="bodyForm">
                    <form class="form-horizontal">';
                        $out.='<fieldset>
                            <legend>Classificador Eventos</legend>';
                            if(true){ //NomeOperador
                                $out.='<div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="filtro_NomeOperador" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label">Usuário</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtro_Nome" disabled value="'.$_SESSION['nomeGuerra'].'">
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }
                            if(true){//Atendimento
                                $out.='<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" for="filtro_Cliente">Atendimento</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="filtro_Cliente" onchange="carregarSubcliente();">';
                                            foreach ($clientes as $t){
                                                $out.='<option value="'.utf8_decode($t['valor']).'">'.utf8_decode($t['valor']).'</option>';
                                            }
                                        $out.='</select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }
                            if(true){ //Solicitante
                                $out.='<div class="form-group" id="div_subcliente">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" for="filtro_Subcliente">Solicitante</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="filtro_Subcliente"></select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }
                            if(true){//Executivo
                            $out.='<fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group" id="div_Executivo">
                                    <label for="filtro_Executivo" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label">Executivo</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="filtro_Executivo">';
                                            foreach ($filtro_Executivo as $b){
                                                $out.='<option value="'.utf8_decode($b['valor']).'">'.utf8_decode($b['valor']).'</option>';
                                            }
                                        $out.='</select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </fieldset>';
                            }
                            if(true){ //IATA
                                $out.='<div class="form-group" id="div_IATA">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" for="filtro_IATA">IATA / OAC</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtro_IATA" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;" id="div_IATA_nome">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtro_IATA_nome" disabled >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group hidden" id="div_alertIATA">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-9 alert-sm alert-danger">
                                        O IATA/OAC deve ser um código válido.
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }
```

Aqui está a function que carrega o Solicitante:

```
    function carregarSubcliente($cliente){

$filtro_atendimento = obtiene_Cliente('subcliente',utf8_decode($cliente));

$out = '<label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" for="filtro_Subcliente">Solicitante</label>
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;">
    <select class="form-control" id="filtro_Subcliente" >';
        foreach ($filtro_atendimento as $a){
            $out .= "<option value='".utf8_decode($a['valor'])."'>".utf8_decode($a['valor'])."</option>";
        }
    $out.='</select>
</div>';
echo $out;
}
```

Eu tentei criar uma function onchange, dentro dessa última function que trás os dados do Solicitante, porém não está dando certo.
Coloquei o nome de "OculparCampos()"
Segue o código que estou tentando utilizar:

```
function carregarSubcliente($cliente){

$filtro_atendimento = obtiene_Cliente('subcliente',utf8_decode($cliente));

$out = '<label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" for="filtro_Subcliente">Solicitante</label>
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;">
    <select class="form-control" id="filtro_Subcliente" onchange="OcultarCampos()">';
        foreach ($filtro_atendimento as $a){
            $out .= "<option value='".utf8_decode($a['valor'])."'>".utf8_decode($a['valor'])."</option>";
        }
        $out.='</select>
    </div>';
echo $out;
}


function OcultarCampos(){

    var valor = document.getElementById("filtro_Subcliente").value;
valor.onchange = function(){
                    if (valor === "AGÊNCIA") {
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA").classList.remove("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA_nome").classList.remove("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_Executivo").classList.add("hidden");
                    } 
                    else if {(valor === "EXECUTIVO")
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA").classList.add("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA_nome").classList.add("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_Executivo").classList.remove("hidden");
                    }
                    else if {(valor === "CORPORATIVO")
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA").classList.remove("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA_nome").classList.remove("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_Executivo").classList.add("hidden");
                    }
                    else {
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA").classList.add("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA_nome").classList.add("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_Executivo").classList.add("hidden");
                        }

}}
```

Ao inserir a parte de ocultar campos, a página está trazendo o erro abaixo:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR) in D:\www\augusta\servicios\classificadorEventos2\classificador_Eventos_ajax2.php on line 204.

A linha 204 é essa:
var valor = document.getElementById("filtro_Subcliente").value;

Desde já agradeço pela atenção pessoal. 
Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

---

Corrigi o erro anterior, utilizando o script abaixo, porém os campos não ficam ocultos.

```
function OcultarCampos(){

        $out.='<script>

                    var valor  = document.getElementById("filtro_Subcliente").value;
                    if (valor === "AGÊNCIA") {
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA").classList.remove("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA_nome").classList.remove("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_Executivo").classList.add("hidden");
                    } 
                    else if {(valor === "EXECUTIVO")
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA").classList.add("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA_nome").classList.add("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_Executivo").classList.remove("hidden");
                    }
                    else if {(valor === "CORPORATIVO")
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA").classList.remove("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA_nome").classList.remove("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_Executivo").classList.add("hidden");
                    }
                    else {
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA").classList.add("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_IATA_nome").classList.add("hidden");
                    document.getElementById("div_Executivo").classList.add("hidden");
                    }
                }
            </script>';
    echo $out;
        }
```

Não apresenta erro, mas continua aparecendo todos os campos, conforme print abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Me parece que estás misturando código PHP com JavaScript, por isso o erro citado. Essa função `OcultarCampos()` é JS e está dentro do bloco de código PHP.

Comment: Entendi Sam.. Obrigado pela informação. 
Como eu faria esse código somente em PHP? 
Pq tudo que achei na net foi em JavaScript :/

Comment: Ocultar campos tem que ser em JS mesmo, a não ser que vc faça um Ajax para puxar os campos que vc quer toda vez que houver um onchange. Me parece que essa função que citei deveria estar entre as tags `<script></script>` no HTML da página.

Comment: Coloquei script no começo e no fim como sugeriu, tive que colocar um $out antes do script para que não ocorresse erro.
Agora não apresenta erro, porém os campos não se ocultam, ficam todos disponíveis..

Comment: Não sei se devo usar alguma outra forma de ocultar, tipo display none, ou visibility "hidden"..